# how to install windows service

Tags: windows-services

I'm working on an MVC .net web application. I need to make a windows service for sending mails to persons from database. After I prepare my windows service how to install it? Anyone can provide steps? 
Actually i don't know how to prepare the service installer

Comment: see the installing section from [here](http://code-studio.blogspot.in/2011/04/create-window-services-using-c.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not specific to ASP.NET MVC. MVC is a framework to develop web applications. It has nothing to do with your Windows service.

You need to create an installer project for your service which will install the service on the computer. This [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a.aspx) explains it well with sample .